# How do you include an object in a html form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, object

I'm trying to add an object to a html form. Object will look like this:

```
let bestilling = {
    btnUndersider1:      500,
    btnUndersider2:      750,
    btnUndersider3:     1500,
    btnUndersider4:     4500,
}
```

I've tried having an invisible input field, and then using the #id.value and also #id.innerHTML, however neither of theese worked out.
It's important that the object is invisible to the customers. 
How do i do this? Thanks.

Comment: Set the `value` attribute to `JSON.stringify(bestilling)`.

Comment: How do you submit the form? Do you rely on the `<form action=...` or you use Javascript code to submit?

Comment: @Pointy the value attribute?

Comment: @niry I'm using BS4, and it's being submitted with a button with the 'type="Submit" '

Comment: The `value` attribute of an `<input>` element. You haven't really described much about what you expect the effect to be of "including" the object in the form.

Comment: @Pointy Perfect, that works great.
Is there a way to seperate them by newline. The list can get pretty long, and right now it just give me a long line of all object values.

Comment: The values of form elements can only be strings; newlines don't matter with JSON. On the server, you'll have to parse the JSON string and reconstruct an object.

Comment: Provide a [mcve]  ... @Pointy If one use `textarea` instead of an `input` newline matters, still, we need a _mcve_ to know more

Comment: @LGSon yes an example would be nice; note that the OP says the field (whether `<input>` or `<textarea>`) is going to be hidden, so it's not clear why it matters at all. In either case it's going to have to be parsed at the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just loop through your object. This creates a new `<span>` and `<input>` for each, with a new line. If you want to make any of them invisible, before `appendChild`, just apply `e.style.visibility = "hidden"` or `"e.style.display = none"`, depending on the layout you want.

```
let bestilling = {
    btnUndersider1:      500,
    btnUndersider2:      750,
    btnUndersider3:     1500,
    btnUndersider4:     4500,
}

for (x=0; x<Object.keys(bestilling).length; x++) {
    e = document.createElement('span');
    e.innerText = Object.keys(bestilling)[x] + " - ";
    document.body.appendChild(e);

    e = document.createElement('input');
    e.value = bestilling[Object.keys(bestilling)[x]];
    document.body.appendChild(e);
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
}
```